# Jstree - uncheck checkbox using node id

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using `Jstree` with checkox theme in my project and I want uncheck the particualar node using the node id on button click event.

I have searched for this on google but not getting any any solution.

Does any one knows how to do this?

Comment: The method uncheck_node worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

below code to `uncheck` selected tree node from `Js` tree.
please try this code

```
$("#tree").jstree("uncheck_node", id of Node to uncheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

uncheck_node method is used for unchecking the checkbox